# Jquery Countup show only hour and minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following [Jquery countup script](https://github.com/ogulcan/jquery-countup). I'm trying to show only hours and minutes but I can't figure out how to do that. And I'm trying to show the hours and minutes with 2 digits with leading zeros.

Could somebody explain to me how I could achieve this?

Comment: Look for the relevant code lines and rewrite them. If you have further questions about certain lines of code, please post those lines

Answer (score 1):

This is the snippet I found in above lib:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#jq_count_up').countUp({'lang':'en', 'format':'full', 'sinceDate': '22/07/2008-00::00'});
        });
```

Now in here, change the value of format. You should follow this lib docs to find out matching format.

Just happened to look into this js file. They have clearly shown the example for this as well...

```
//example: $.countUp({ 'sinceDate':'01/01/2011', 'lang':'en', 'format':'day' });
//date format: dd/mm/yyyy-hh:mm:ss
//available langs: english (en), turkish (tr), deutsch (de), spanish (es)
//format options: full, day, seconds
```